# How long does payout take for Real Estate Royale?

Tags: yakuza-0

In the Real Estate Royale minigame, I've noticed that when you start each property takes a different amount of time to payout. The Leisure King area seems to be the fastest while the Media King Area is the slowest.

How long does it take for each property to payout?

[image: Real Estate property menu]

Answer (score 1):

> For level 4 upgrade:
>
> - Leisure King: 6 minutes
> - Electronics King: 7 minutes
> - Pleasure King: 8 minutes
> - Gambling King: 10 minutes

This is from a top voted answer on [Gamefaqs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/ps4/816306-yakuza-0/answers/453851-revenue-speed-levels).

Media King time is missing, but it's probably a little more that the others.